# eigen auto type deduction in general product

Tags: c++, c++11, eigen, eigen3

I have the following piece of code (I apologize for the slightly larger code
snippet, this is the minimal example I was able to reduce my problem to):

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <complex>
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

// Dynamic Matrix over Scalar field
template <typename Scalar> 
using DynMat = Eigen::Matrix<Scalar, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic>;

// Dynamic column vector over Scalar field
template <typename Scalar>
using DynVect = Eigen::Matrix<Scalar, Eigen::Dynamic, 1>;

// Returns the D x D Identity matrix over the field Derived::Scalar
// deduced from the expression Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>& A
template<typename Derived>
DynMat<typename Derived::Scalar> Id(const Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>& A, std::size_t D)
{   
    DynMat<typename Derived::Scalar> result =
            DynMat<typename Derived::Scalar>::Identity(D, D);

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    //using ScalarField = std::complex<double>; // same issue even if I use complex numbers
    using ScalarField = double; // we use doubles in this example

    // A double dynamic matrix (i.e. MatrixXd)
    DynMat<ScalarField> Foo; // used to deduce the type in Id<>()

    // A double dynamic column vector (i.e. VectorXd)
    DynVect<ScalarField> v(4);
    v << 1., 0. , 0. ,0.; // plug in some values into it

    // Make sure that Id(Foo, 4) correctly deduces the template parameters
    std::cout << "Id(Foo, 4) is indeed the 4 x 4 identiy matrix over the ScalarField of "
              << "typeid().name(): " << typeid(ScalarField).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << Id(Foo, 4) << std::endl; // Indeed the 4 x 4 complex Identity matrix

    // Use auto type deduction for GenMatProduct, junk is displayed. Why?!
    std::cout << std::endl << "Use auto type deduction for GenMatProduct,\
                 sometimes junk is displayed. Why?!" << std::endl;
    auto autoresult = Id(Foo, 4) * v; // evaluated result must be identically equal to v
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
            std::cout << autoresult.transpose(); // thought 1 0 0 0 is the result, but NO, junk
            std::cout << " has norm: " << autoresult.norm() << std::endl; // junk
    }

    // Use implicit cast to Dynamic Matrix, works fine
    std::cout << std::endl << "Use implicit cast to Dynamic Matrix, works fine" << std::endl;
    DynMat<ScalarField> castresult = Id(Foo, 4) * v; // evaluated result must be identically equal to v
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
            std::cout << castresult.transpose(); // 1 0 0 0, works ok
            std::cout << " has norm: " << castresult.norm() << std::endl; // ok
    }
}
```

The main idea is that the template function `Id<>()` takes an Eigen expression `A` 
as a parameter, together with a size `D`, and produces the identity matrix
over the scalar field of the expression `A`. This function by itself works fine. However,
when I use it in an Eigen product with `auto` deduced type, such as in the line
`auto autoresult = Id(Foo, 4) * v`, I would expect to multiply the vector `v` 
by the identity matrix, so the net result should be an expression which,
when evaluated, should be identically equal to `v`. But this is not the case,
see the first `for` loop, whenever I display the result and computes its norm,
I get most of the time junk. If, on the other hand, I implicitly cast 
the Eigen product `Id(Foo, 4) * v` to a dynamic matrix, everything works fine,
the result is properly evaluated.

I use Eigen 3.2.2 on OS X Yosemite, and get the same weird 
behaviour both with g++4.9.1 and 
Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.54) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)

**QUESTION:**

- I do not understand what is happening in the first `for` loop, why
  isn't the product evaluated when I use `std::cout`, or even when I
  use the `norm` method? Am I missing something? There is no aliasing
  involved here, and I am really  puzzled by what is going on. I know
  that Eigen uses lazy evaluation, and evaluates the expression when
  needed, but this doesn't seem to be the  case here. This problem is
  extremely important for me, as I have lots  of functions of the same
  flavour as `Id<>()`, which when used in `auto`  deduced expressions
  may fail.

The problem occurs quite often, but not always. However, if you run the
program 3-4 times, you will definitely see it.

The command I use to compile and run it is:

```
clang++ (g++) -std=c++11 -isystem ./eigen_3.2.2/ testeigen.cpp -otesteigen; ./testeigen
```

A typical output I got in a real run is:

```
Id(Foo, 4) is indeed the 4 x 4 identiy matrix over the ScalarField of typeid().name(): d
1 0 0 0
0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0
0 0 0 1

Use GenMatProduct, sometimes junk is displayed. Why?!
1 0 0 0 has norm: inf
3.10504e+231 3.10504e+231 3.95253e-323            0 has norm: inf
3.10504e+231 3.10504e+231 3.95253e-323            0 has norm: inf
3.10504e+231 3.10504e+231 3.95253e-323            0 has norm: inf
3.10504e+231 3.10504e+231 3.95253e-323            0 has norm: inf
3.10504e+231 3.10504e+231 3.95253e-323            0 has norm: inf
3.10504e+231 3.10504e+231 3.95253e-323            0 has norm: inf
3.10504e+231 3.10504e+231 3.95253e-323            0 has norm: inf
3.10504e+231 3.10504e+231 3.95253e-323            0 has norm: inf
3.10504e+231 3.10504e+231 3.95253e-323            0 has norm: inf

Use implicit cast to Dynamic Matrix, works fine
1 0 0 0 has norm: 1
1 0 0 0 has norm: 1
1 0 0 0 has norm: 1
1 0 0 0 has norm: 1
1 0 0 0 has norm: 1
1 0 0 0 has norm: 1
1 0 0 0 has norm: 1
1 0 0 0 has norm: 1
1 0 0 0 has norm: 1
1 0 0 0 has norm: 1
```

Even if I use `eval()` in

```
  std::cout << autoresult.eval().transpose(); // thought 1 0 0 0 is the result, but NO, junk
  std::cout << " has norm: " << autoresult.eval().norm() << std::endl; // junk
```

I am getting the same weird behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `Id()` returns a temporary which is stored by reference in the object representing the expression `Id(Foo, 4) * v`. Thus after the auto statement, `autoresult` stores a reference to a dead object. If you do not want an abstract expression but the actual result, do not use `auto` or call `eval` to enforce evaluation:

```
auto autoresult = (Id(Foo, 4) * v).eval();
```

A third option is to make the object returned by `Id()` available for further computations:

```
auto id4 = Id(Foo,4);
auto autoresult = id4 * v;
```

but in this case, anytime you use `autoresult` then the product will be re-evaluated and the following will output different results:

```
cout << autoresult;
v.setRandom();
cout << autoresult;
```

Comment: Thanks much! One last question: Isn't the temporary object stored via a const reference binding to the temporary, so the lifetime of the temporary is the same as the lifetime of the expression?

Comment: Yes the temporary is stored via a const reference, but this does not extent its lifetime because there is one indirection. This lifetime extension mechanism is not transitive.

Answer (score 1):

It probably has a lazy evaluation type that is only safe to evaluate once.  You could capture it with:

```
auto autoresultmatrix = autoresult.eval()
```

Comment: Thanks, I know that if I force evaluation it works (when doing a cast the evaluation is forced), however this makes the code much uglier in general, especially when dealing with complicated expressions. I would have liked to write something like `myfunc(A*A+B-C)`, where `myfunc` is some function that takes an Eigen expression and spits out the result of the computation as a dynamic matrix, and I though that it will be perfectly fine to use it later in expressions like `myfunc(A*A+B-C) * D`, without the need for `eval`. Especially when calling methods like `norm`, which SHOULD force evaluation.

Comment: @vsoftco The transpose + print is evaluating and consuming the result.  If you did the norm first it would work.  I suggested the eval because I thought your concern was being unable to use auto.

Comment: And even if I first do `std::cout << result.norm()`, still get the same behaviour, i.e. junk is being displayed.

Comment: Basically my question is how to write a function that takes an arbitrary Eigen expression as a parameter, then computes the result ALWAYS (so when I use `cout<<f(expression)` I do not have lazy evaluation, but want `f(expression)` to be evaluated).

Comment: And as a last comment, if instead of the `autoresult` I use directly `(Id(Foo, 4) * v).transpose()`, then it works. I am really a bit puzzled, as I see no difference between `(Id(Foo, 4) * v).transpose()` and `autoresult.transpose()`, except that in the first case one has a temporary.