# Eigen equivalent to Octave/MATLAB mldivide for rectangular matrices

Tags: c++, matlab, octave, linear-algebra, eigen

I'm using Eigen v3.2.7.

I have a medium-sized rectangular matrix `X` (170x17) and row vector `Y` (170x1) and I'm trying to solve them using Eigen.  Octave solves this problem fine using `X\Y`, but Eigen is returning incorrect values for these matrices (but not smaller ones) - however I suspect that it's how I'm using Eigen, rather than Eigen itself.

```
auto X = Eigen::Matrix<T, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic>{170, 17};
auto Y = Eigen::Matrix<T, Eigen::Dynamic, 1>{170};

// Assign their values...

const auto theta = X.colPivHouseholderQr().solve(Y).eval(); // Wrong!
```

According to the Eigen [documentation](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TutorialLinearAlgebra.html), the `ColPivHouseholderQR` solver is for general matrices and pretty robust, but to make sure I've also tried the `FullPivHouseholderQR`.  The results were identical.

Is there some special magic that Octave's `mldivide` does that I need to implement manually for Eigen?

### Update

[This spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mhAiXbet0GMRvkYy_tOYmU-y8KcCxh_h74a1nbK5jiM/edit?usp=sharing) has the two input matrices, plus Octave's and my result matrices.

Replacing `auto` doesn't make a difference, nor would I expect it to because construction cannot be a lazy operation, and I have to call `.eval()` on the solve result because the next thing I do with the result matrix is get at the raw data (using `.data()`) on tail and head operations.  The expression template versions of the result of those block operations do not have a `.data()` member, so I have to force evaluation beforehand - in other words `theta` is the concrete type already, not an expression template.

The result for `(X*theta-Y).norm()/Y.norm()` is:

```
2.5365e-007
```

And the result for `(X.transpose()*X*theta-X.transpose()*Y).norm() / (X.transpose()*Y).norm()` is:

```
2.80096e-007
```

As I'm currently using single precision float for my basic numerical type, that's pretty much zero for both.

Comment: it would be better if you provide data to reproduce the error.

Comment: if the question is not how to fix it , but why this is so, then look on this  answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18553768/4651282

Comment: You want me to paste a 170x17 floating point matrix!?

Comment: you can't upload them somewhere and leave a link?

Comment: Just a guess (I'm still waking up): Don't use `auto` with Eigen. See e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31099246/wrong-results-using-auto-with-eigen) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26925302/2899559).

Comment: How did you check that the result is incorrect? First, as Avi said, replace auto by `Eigen::VectorXd`, then print `(X*theta-Y).norm()/Y.norm()` as well as `(X.transpose()*X*theta-X.transpose()*Y).norm() / (X.transpose()*Y).norm()`.

Comment: @Atomic_alarm - I've updated my question with your response.  Thanks for your time!

Comment: @ggael - I've updated my question with your response. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your verifications, the solution you get is perfectly fine. If you want more accuracy, then use `double` floating point numbers. Note that MatLab/Octave use double precision by default.

Moreover, it might also likely be that your problem is not full rank, in which case your problem admit an infinite number of solution. ColPivHouseholderQR picks one, somehow arbitrarily. On the other hand, mldivide will pick the minimal norm one that you can also obtain with `Eigen::BDCSVD` (Eigen 3.3), or the slower `Eigen::JacobiSVD`.

Comment: So are you saying that although the result I get from Eigen is not the same as Octave - it is equivalent?  I tried using `JacobiSVD`, but it gave me a different result to Octave (regardless of the 'thin'/'full' U/V state).

Comment: Yes or no. The values you get confirm that Eigen find one solution of the problem you asked. But maybe you are not asking for the exact same problem. If you want to dig deeper, then 1) make sure you use double for the comparison, 2) print the norm of the solution for both Eigen and Octave, 3) print the singular values `(X.jacobiSvd().singularValues().transpose())`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, after plotting the frequency and phase response of what I'm getting from Eigen against Octave (my result is a polynomial ratio representing an IIR), they're pretty close.  Close enough that it is probably a precision problem, I'll investigate further.

Comment: Even using single precision, when I tried to reproduce your issues I got the "exact" same result as Octave (both with and without auto). See [link](https://ideone.com/jYEjpB), just edit it to copy paste to your favorite editor. What compiler etc. are you using?

Comment: I also get the same as Avi. Maybe you are miss-parsing the `-9.11E-05` and similar entries if using a text file to exchange data?

Comment: I'm converting a MATLAB script to C++, and the `X` and `Y` matrices are generated from other input data.  I've compared the C++ matrices to Octave's and they are exactly the same, so I know the code up until point I solve them is correct.  Interestingly, if I change to double precision then my frequency response graphs then match Octave's accurately - implying that the solve results are equivalent, but not the same.  What version of Eigen are you using?

Comment: @cmannett85 Same as you, 3.2.7. I compiled using VS2013. I can compile with g++ (Windows / Ubuntu) if that matches your toolchain. Did you copy and compile the MCVE?

Comment: @AviGinsburg I get the same results with v3.2.5 on MinGW64 and 3.2.7 on Linux (both using g++ 5.2.1).  I haven't tried using MSVC.

Comment: Interesting. Using double precision I get the same results between VS2013 and MinGW g++ 4.8.1. Using single precision, I get different results with the two compilers.