# Explicit type declaration Vs auto in Eigen expressions in C++

Tags: c++, eigen

I am using Eigen library in c++ and encountered a strange issue.

```
Eigen::VectorXd someV(){
  Eigen::VectorXd a(3);
  a(1)=1.2;
  a(2)=2.3;
  a(0)=3.2;
  return a;
}

int main(){
  auto c=2.*someV();
  std::cout<<c;
  return 0;
}
```

does not return anything. However,

```
int main(){
  auto c=someV();
  c *= 2.;
  std::cout<<c;
  return 0;
}
```

returns the desired result. Also note that explicit type declaration solves the issue.

```
int main(){
  Eigen::VectorXd c=2.*someV();
  std::cout<<c;
  return 0;
}
```

Why is the use of auto in first case incorrect?

Comment: I'd suspect this has something to do with the interaction of casts and `auto`. Could you try not using `auto', but be explicit with the return types and see if the behavior differs?

Comment: What kind of values are you getting, and what kind do you expect?

Comment: Please could you include an SSCCE (http://sscce.org/) so that we don't have to guess what the inputs are, how the result is different to what you're expecting, etc.

Comment: @user2178841 You should avoid `auto` type deduction on Eigen expressions (like `x * x`), as the type deduced is a temporary expression template, which may become invalid after the statement ends (as the expression itself was a temporary). See e.g. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26705446/eigen-auto-type-deduction-in-general-product). Or, you can try adding `.eval()` to fully evaluate the expression, like `(x*x).eval() * func()`.

Comment: @vsoftco Yeah, I realized after following TriskalJM's advice. Explicit type declaration gives correct result. You can post that as answer. I will slightly modify the question so that this becomes more useful to other users.

Comment: Eigen uses expression templates. And it seems from your examples that the expressions template is not handled completely by the library.   In your example `c` contains an expression (and possibly with invalid references), and not a real matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eigen uses expression templates to allow for expressions to be optimized. This means that the return type is not an instance of `Eigen::VectorXd` and is instead a template representing the operation which evaluates everything when it is assigned back to a vector. In your case the type returned is of type

```
Eigen::MatrixBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1>>::ScalarMultipleReturnType
```

which is a typedef of

```
Eigen::CwiseUnaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_multiple_op<double>, const Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1>>
```

Normally, this would be fine, the result is be converted back into a vector when it is assigned. In your case, though, it is not converted back since the `auto` is deducted to be the temporary result type. This was probably not intended by the library authors and is the cause of the problems you were having with printing it.

With your second case, the `auto` is deduced as being of type `Eigen::VectorXd`. This poses no problems when printing it using `std::cout`.

Comment: Actually, this is a very common mistake and the [authors warn](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicPitfalls.html) about using `auto` if you don't know what you're doing.

Comment: And to be more precise, the true problem here is that the object `c` of type `CwiseUnaryOp` stores a reference to the vector returned by `someV`. This temporary is deleted right after, and this reference thus becomes invalid... On the other hand, the following is fine: `cout << 2.*someV();`